# Chrome not rendering svg for fonts when hash included

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, svg, font-face

Chrome renders SVG fonts better than TTF, so I wanted to force it to use the SVG files. But when I only include the SVG in my declaration, Chrome doesn't find/apply the font. If I remove the hash symbol, it *does* apply it (likely the first thing found in the svg)! What am I doing wrong?

**file structure**

```
/
/fonts
/styles
```

**styles.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "TeXGyreHerosCnBoldItalic";
    src: url( "../fonts/texgyreheroscn-bolditalic-webfont.svg#TeXGyreHerosCnBoldItalic" ) format("svg" );
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

**html**

```
<div style="font-family: 'TeXGyreHerosCnBold';">Some text</div>
```

If I instead do this, it works:

```
src: url( "../fonts/texgyreheroscn-bolditalic-webfont.svg" ) format("svg" );
```

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042387/svg-spritesheet-targeting-with-css

Comment: @cimmanon Thank you, it looks to be the same. Can you explain why it's a securtiy risk? I don't see how loading the SVG vs loading only the part defined by teh `#name` is a security risk.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too certain why this is a security issue, and the linked bug report doesn't go into details.  Google isn't very helpful here either.  I can only guess that it has something to do with accessing browsing history similar to this:  http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/visited_links_can_only_be_differentiated_by_colour/

Comment: @cimmanon Can you post your comment as an answer instead so i can mark this question answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @cinnamon, it seems to be the Chrome team deciding that you should not be able to traverse an SVG: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128055#c6

@Cinnamon has more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16042903/857025