# Detect browser support for SVGFragmentIdentifier(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am using SVG sprites with SVGFragmentIdentifiers. like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <style><![CDATA[
        .sprite { display: none; }
        .sprite:target { display: inline; }
    ]]></style>
</defs>
<g class="sprite" id="icon1">...</g>
<g class="sprite" id="icon2">...</g>
<g class="sprite" id="icon3">...</g>
</svg>
```

Of course I am using the SVG file via CSS background etc:

```
.icon1 {
  background-image: url(mysprite.svg#icon1);
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Unfortunately SVG Fragment Identifiers are not supported in webkit and other browsers at this time: http://caniuse.com/svg-fragment

I am using Modernizr to check for browser features. Is it possible to make a Modernizr or independent JavaScript Browsercheck for SVGFragmentIdentifiers?

I thought about creating an SVG object via jQuery and triggering a `:target` event about it. Later I might check whether it is hidden or shown. maybe jQuery's `event.target` might help here. But am not sure whether that is fitting for background images, because it would be a matter of inline svg's.

Any ideas?

Comment: For what it's worth, browsers aren't really *supposed* to support fragment identifiers like this.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042387/svg-spritesheet-targeting-with-css

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try following approach (I'm confused if `View` is the right one to check the support for Fragment Identifiers):

```
function supportsSvgView() {
    return document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#View", "1.1");
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFfN/) in various browsers. [Read more here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) and check [all feature strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature) for (1.0 & 1.1).

Comment: I don't think that's a reliable way to check for it. Also there's recently been talk about making the hasFeature method always return "true", see this thread: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2014Jan/0042.html.

Comment: hasFeature will always return true except for svg features so the answer should be correct https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature

Comment: i have been testing a bit and it turns out that non of this features refers to svg fragments