# SVG Spritesheets using SYMBOL CSS SVG Fragment in CSS as background: url or similar? if not why?

Tags: html, css, svg

****Can we do this?****
Use SYMBOL CSS SVG Fragment USE in CSS as background: url or similar?
It seems to me, all other things being equal, SYMBOL use does not work, where G with separate viewbox works. If this cannot be done, why? Is there a better way to do SVG Spritesheets?

SYMBOL has an ID, has a viewBox..am I doing somthing wrong or using symbol inc. viewbox, VS, separate viewbox & g = Does Not Work? oO

Am I doing somthing wrong, or, does the below CSS SVG fragment usage only work with the separate viewbox and G (and not work with symbol with viewbox)?

**SYMBOL SVG**

```
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(360)" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="basket">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#626262" stroke-width="2" d="M2 12h20l-2 11H4L2 12zm18-4l-6-7M4 8l6-7M1 8h22v4H1V8zm7 7v5m8-5v5m-4-5v5"></path>
    <path fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
</symbol>
```

..VS..

**G & VIEWBOX SVG**

```
<view id="icon-clock-view" viewBox="0 0 32 32" />
<g id="icon-clock">
    <path d="M20.6,23.3L14,16.7V7.9h4v7.2l5.4,5.4L20.6,23.3z M16-0.1c-8.8,0-16,7.2-16,16s7.2,16,16,16s16-7.2,16-16S24.8-0.1,16-0.1z
         M16,27.9c-6.6,0-12-5.4-12-12s5.4-12,12-12s12,5.4,12,12S22.6,27.9,16,27.9z"/>
</g>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-clock {background: url(https://example.com/svg-defs.svg#icon-clock-view) no-repeat;}
.basket {background: url(https://example.com/svg-defs.svg#basket) no-repeat;}
```

Comment: The shapes nested inside a `<symbol>` are not displayed unless referenced by a `<use>`element. You can use a nested svg instead. Please read this article about [How SVG fragment identifiers work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: Well this is annoying! Why didnt this get adpoted as standard? Very silly or is there a reason? Did somthing else become the standard use for this kind of thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to works great. Using 'name' as example to follow.

Wrap `<path>(s) & </path>` within `<symbol> </symbol>` I did not use `<g>`

Add `id="name"` to `<symbol>` e.g. `<symbol id="name">`

Outside the symbol tags, add a `<view>` and a `<use>`. The URL, where the complete file is uploaded to, and view ID will become your SVG Fragment.

```
<view id="icon-name-view" viewBox="0 1240 16 16" />
<use xlink:href="#icon-name" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="1240" id="name"></use>
```

Change the viewbox to locate the SVG in the spritesheet, here I'd used Y axis, this particular SVG is located at Y axis 1240. Save the SVG Spritesheet to say, svg-defs.svg.

In your CSS use the SVG spritesheet URL with the Fragment Ident e.g.

```
background: url(https://example.com/svg/svg-defs.svg#icon-name-view) no-repeat;
```

To change colours I was using filter, e.g.

```
filter: invert(80%) sepia(21%) saturate(872%) hue-rotate(44deg) brightness(84%) contrast(91%);
```

Positioning can be done with the ViewBox's but I also used transform, translate.

```
transform: translateY (10px);
```

Hope you find this useful, I hope to write a complete guide and will link it when I do. Thank you.